# Convex function parameter

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I need to find the parameter $a$ such that $$f(x)= x^2-a|3x-1|+4$$ is convex on $[0,1]$. I saw that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and then I calculated the first derivate and put the condition that the derivative should also be continuous so that the second one exists. From this condition I find that $a$ should be  $0$ but in the book the answer is $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: shouldn't the first derivate be continous in order for the second one to exist?

Comment: Although in high school convexity is dealt ony in the case of functions which are $C^2$ (for the sake of calculating a second deirvative, for instance), convex functions need not be twice differentiable. Actually, not even $f'$ is required to exist (and in a lot of cases it does not exists).

Comment: and if I have a function g defined on R and g(x)=f(x)(6x-2) when would this function be differantiable?

Comment: This seems unrelated.

Comment: If $a\leq 0$ we have that $f(x)$ is convex, since it equals the sum of two convex functions. If $a>0$ we have that $f'$ *decreases* going from the left to the right of $\frac{1}{3}$, hence $f$ cannot be convex.

Answer (score 2):

$1)$ for $x\in(0,1/3)$ then

$$f(x)= x^2+a(3x-1)+4\to f'(x)=2x+3a$$

$2)$ for $x\in(1/3,1)$ then

$$f(x)= x^2-a(3x-1)+4\to f'(x)=2x-3a$$

the intersection beetween $(1)$ and $(2)$ happens at $x_i=1/3$

look that

$$\lim_{x\to 1/3^{-}} f'(x)=\frac{2}{3}+3a$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1/3^{+}} f'(x)=\frac{2}{3}-3a$$

one condition for guarentee convexity is $f'(x)$ increasing around the intersection $1/3$, not necessarily continuous. Here we are taking advantage that $f$ is a quadratic function, per parts.

So,

$$\lim_{x\to 1/3^{-}} f'(x)\le \lim_{x\to 1/3^{+}} f'(x)$$

$$\frac{2}{3}+3a\le \frac{2}{3}-3a\to a\le 0$$

Comment: why does fx has to be increasing around the intersection? how does that affect convexity?

Comment: Because, if $f''>0$ exist, it means that $f'$ is increasing. But you still can have this condition without $f''$ exist everywhere.

Comment: @Lola: is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

When $a=0$, the function can be written as $f(x) = x^2 + 4$ is a straightforward convex parabola. This is the result you correctly found, but there is more.

Given the absolute value, you can write the function as
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
x^2 - 3ax + a + 4 & \mbox{if } x \ge 1/3 \\
x^2 + 3ax - a + 4 & \mbox{if } x < 1/3 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$
Therefore, if $a \ne 0$, the function has a kink at $x=1/3$.

Note that $f^\prime (x) = 2x \pm 3a$ is everywhere increasing for $x\ne 1/3$. Moreover, the left-hand and right-hand derivative at $x=1/3$ are, respectively,  $f^\prime_-(1/3) = 2/3 + a$ and $f^\prime_+(1/3) = 2/3 - a$. Then convexity follows if $f^\prime_-(1/3) \le f^\prime_+(1/3)$ or $2/3 + a \le 2/3 - a$ from which you get $a \le 0$.

Comment: Shouldn't I put the same condition if I want $x^2-|x-a|$ to be convex on [0,1] when a is in [0,1] because here,if I put this condition it doesnt give me the right answer

Comment: Or is it because a is in [0,1] then the 2x-a will always be < 2x+a so I only need a=0